# Support Whatever ranges in multidimensional subscript access with AT-POS

Tags: raku

How can I implement `AT-POS` such that it supports multidimensional Whatever ranges, like `[0;*]` and `[*;0]`?

In the implementation below, I get `Index out of range` errors:

```
class Foo {
    has @.grid;
    multi method elems { @!grid.elems }
    multi method AT-POS($y, $x) is rw { @!grid[ $y ; $x ] }
    multi method ASSIGN-POS ($y, $x, $new) { @!grid[ $y; $x ] = $new }
    multi method EXISTS-POS($y, $x) { @!grid[ $y; $x ]:exists }
}

my $foo = Foo.new: :grid[ ['a'], ['b', 'c'] ];
say $foo[0;0];         # a
say $foo[0;*].elems;   # Expect 1, get 2
say $foo[0;*];         # Expect (a), get "Index out of range"
say $foo[*;0];         # Expect (a b), get "Index out of range"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#method_AT-POS) says the API is `AT-POS($index)`.

When I replace your `AT-POS` with:

```
    multi method AT-POS($index) is rw { @!grid[ $index ] }
```

your test cases give the results you expect.

Your `ASSIGN-POS` is unnecessary and may make things go wrong.